# Lightgbm stoppong after 10 trees - R

Tags: r, lightgbm

I am trying to run lightGBM in R and the algorithm stops very quickly (after only 10 trees).

This is what I get:

```
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of positive: 16271, number of negative: 430138
[LightGBM] [Info] Total Bins 1359
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of data: 446409, number of used features: 57
[LightGBM] [Info] Trained a tree with leaves=32 and max_depth=8
[1]:    train's binary_logloss:0.366686 eval's binary_logloss:0.36689 
[LightGBM] [Info] Trained a tree with leaves=32 and max_depth=8
[2]:    train's binary_logloss:0.250034 eval's binary_logloss:0.250388 
[LightGBM] [Info] Trained a tree with leaves=32 and max_depth=9
[3]:    train's binary_logloss:0.196744 eval's binary_logloss:0.19725 
[LightGBM] [Info] Trained a tree with leaves=32 and max_depth=8
[4]:    train's binary_logloss:0.17159  eval's binary_logloss:0.172322 
[LightGBM] [Info] Trained a tree with leaves=32 and max_depth=10
[5]:    train's binary_logloss:0.159984 eval's binary_logloss:0.160933 
[LightGBM] [Info] Trained a tree with leaves=32 and max_depth=11
[6]:    train's binary_logloss:0.154829 eval's binary_logloss:0.156185 
[LightGBM] [Info] Trained a tree with leaves=32 and max_depth=11
[7]:    train's binary_logloss:0.152656 eval's binary_logloss:0.154555 
[LightGBM] [Info] Trained a tree with leaves=32 and max_depth=13
[8]:    train's binary_logloss:0.151564 eval's binary_logloss:0.153874 
[LightGBM] [Info] Trained a tree with leaves=32 and max_depth=14
[9]:    train's binary_logloss:0.150981 eval's binary_logloss:0.153697 
[LightGBM] [Info] Trained a tree with leaves=32 and max_depth=11
[10]:   train's binary_logloss:0.150517 eval's binary_logloss:0.153833
```

I am running this code:

```
i.fold=folds!=i

train1 <- lgb.Dataset(train[i.fold,], label = Y[i.fold])
train2 <- lgb.Dataset(train[!i.fold,], label = Y[!i.fold])

valids <- list(eval = train2, train = train1)

set.seed(200+10*i)

param <- list(num_leaves = 32,
              learning_rate = 0.5,
              nthread = 8,
              silent = 1,
              objective = "binary",
              boosting = "gbdt",
              min_data_in_leaf = 1,
              feature_fraction = 1,
              bagging_fraction = 0.8,
              bagging_freq = 0,
              nrounds = 500,
              num_iteration = 500,
              num_iterations = 500,
              num_tree = 500,
              num_trees = 500,
              num_round = 500,
              num_rounds = 500,
              iterace = 10000,
              early_stopping_rounds = 500)


LGBM = lgb.train(param, train1, valid = valids)
```

I've included among parameters every alternative I could find for number of iterations, this is why there are so many parameters with value 500 at the end.

Do you have any idea why it stops so early?

Thank you,
Vlad

Answer (score 0):

**aa = lgb.train(params,
                   d_train,
                   valid_sets=[d_train, d_test],
                   num_boost_round=8000,
                   feature_name=f_names,
                   verbose_eval=10,
                   early_stopping_rounds = 6000)**

I have just copied this from one of my LightGBM training codes, use num_boost_round as above to set the iteration count as you wish.

Hope that is your answer,

Regards,